# arduino atmega32u4 beetle extract hex code

Tags: avrdude, atmega32u4

I made a program using the Arduino Atmega32U4.

As a security issue, I tried to extract the hex code because I wanted to know if this program was duplicated.

avrdude -C"\avrdude.conf" -v -V -patmega32u4 -carduino -PCOM15 -b9600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\test\sketch_jun07b.ino.hex:i

This is what I executed in Command Line.

Avrdude ended with the following error: avrdude: stk500_getsync () attempt 1 of 10: not in sync:

Can you tell me if there is no risk of extracting and duplicating hex code from beetle or chipset unlike arduino board?

Comment: what does the error message mean?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ... what do you mean by `unlike arduino board`?   ... what kind of risk are you talking about?

Comment: I know that I can extract hex code from the Arduino board, is this information wrong? I'm trying it and that's the biggest risk

Comment: yes you can read the content of memory .... i suggest that you investigate the error message before you go further .... you still have not said what risk you are talking about

Comment: Launched Arduino USB type product.
I don't want this product duplicated, so I've run a hex code extraction beforehand.
Connecting to programmer: .. Now I face to face this error... TT

Comment: What programmer? Connected via ISP I suppose? You would probably want `-c stk500v1`in that case. Also, `-U flash:w:xyz:i` tries to *write* a hex file to your device, with xyz being the path. You'd want that to be `-U flash:r:xyz:i`

Comment: Just set a lock bits properly and it won't be so easy to read out the flash.